# Visual Studio Project - MSBuild Target - AfterBuild - Condition - Only When Binary File Updated

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I have a long afterbuild process on my Visual Studio project file's after build target, as show below.

The issue is that it always runs the AfterBuild target when I hit build even when the actual source code has not changed and the project is not compiled.

How can I have this only run when the project has been compiled and the physical binary is written or update on the disk?

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">

 <Exec Command="&quot;$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe&quot; /copyattrs /log /target:library /targetplatform:4,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 /Lib:&quot;$(TargetDir)\&quot; /keyfile:&quot;$(ProjectDir)\Plugin.snk&quot; /out:&quot;$(TargetDir)\$(AssemblyName).merged.dll&quot; &quot;$(AssemblyName).dll&quot; &quot;PluginCommandCommon.dll&quot; &quot;Common.dll&quot;" />

 <Copy SourceFiles="$(TargetDir)\$(AssemblyName).merged.dll" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)..\PluginPackage\bin\$(Configuration)\" />

</Target>
```

Comment: You may look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516227/suppressing-afterbuild-targets-when-a-csproj-has-not-been-built

Comment: Yes, this looks like the answers is the link, will investigate more

Comment: Can't really make sense of the answer in the link, I think I'm missing something.  Effectively all I want to do is run some ms build tasks when ever the project has been build and files have been written to the bin dir.

Answer (score 5):

Option 1:
Instead of **AfterBuild** use **AfterRebuild** (one of MSBuild's many undocumented features):

```
<Target Name="AfterRebuild" >...</Target>
```

Option 2:

Hook up one of the [incremental build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171483.aspx)'s conditions:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition=" '@(_SourceItemsToCopyToOutputDirectory)' != '' " >
```

---

*UPDATE*:

Using [MSBuild Extension Pack](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/)'s [ILMerge task](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.5.0/html/369d361e-869f-0a4b-2e37-d58ba332735a.htm) will allow better control, I.E check for each file existence:

```
<Target Name="ILMergeItems">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Input Include="C:\b\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll"/>
        <Input Include="C:\b\Ionic.Zip.dll"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.ILMerge
        Condition="Exists('%(Input.FullPath)')"
        InputAssemblies="@(Input)"
        OutputFile="C:\a\MyNewAssembly.dll"/>
</Target>
```

Comment: OK, tried both with odd results, the first does not seem to fire at all and the later does not always fire, for example, if I add some code and  hit shift F6 (build current project), it still does not run.

Comment: The first should run on `Rebuild`; The second when there's a change in the output files. Isn't that what you asked for? If not please clarify your question

Comment: Thanks for your time, Yes that is my requirement but what's missing is that I'm using Visual Studio and if you try these in Visual Studio they simply do not behave as expected, I've just made a load of changes to a DLL and the target AfterBuild with the condition specified above and it failed to execute even though 11 files were copied into the bin folder? I've even tried deleting all the files in bin folder, it still does not execute the target on build.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'd avoid using `<Exec>` task. See my updated answer which covers the MSBuild Extension Pack method of doing it the managed way.

Comment: Thanks for the ILMerge task that does look a lot cleaner to implement.  During my even task firing I took ILMerge out of the target(s), so I still have the issue with the targets in Visual Studio not firing as expected.  I can get the rebuild target to fire if I do a Rebuild All but that defeats the point, where I want very granular control of target firing only when a file has changed.  I'm on the verge of giving up and just using individual batch files to perform the merge when building debug versions and add a condition when the build type is Release.

Comment: Option 2 worked nicely.  I've burned two hours on this.  No idea why it is so obscure.

Answer (score -2):

There is a ComboBox in Properties>>Build Events>>Run the post-build event...if this is what you mean.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, but that's not the answer I'm looking for.