# MSBuild VC2012, how to make sure AfterBuild only runs when the output is changed?

Tags: visual-c++, msbuild

I'm trying to add an AfterBuild task to my VC++2012 project that only gets executed if the output changes. If I'm correct, in C# when you're adding a post-build-event, you have the option to specify when to run the post-build-event. I tried adding condition such as **_SourceItemsToCopyToOutputDirectory** but it doesn't help, it's empty whether I'm doing a null build or not. The only property I found is **LinkSkippedExecution** but I'm not sure it's the best option.

Thanks for your help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run an MSBuild target only if project is actually built](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972820/run-an-msbuild-target-only-if-project-is-actually-built)

Comment: thanks stijn, looks like the post is for c# project and possibly using a different attribute (_AssemblyTimestampBeforeCompile), I'll give it a go.

Comment: yeah I'm not sure it's an exact duplicate, but if it's not it should at least get you started since I'm pretty sure the c++ build system uses a similar approach of recording timestamps

Comment: I don't think I can use _AssemblyTimestamp, just printing it, I get null. <Target Name="AfterBuild" >
    <Message Text="assembly time before is $(_AssemblyTimestampBeforeCompile) after is $(_AssemblyTimestampAfterCompile)" /> and here is what I get: Task "Message" (TaskId:33)
                     Task Parameter:Text=assembly time before is  after is  (TaskId:33)
                     assembly time before is  after is  (TaskId:33)
                   Done executing task "Message". (TaskId:33)

Answer (score 2):

[Check out this stack overflow question and answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516227/suppressing-afterbuild-targets-when-a-csproj-has-not-been-built)
You can create a property in the before build target based on the timestamp of the output files.

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <MyBeforeCompileTimestamp>%(IntermediateAssembly.ModifiedTime)
                 </MyBeforeCompileTimestamp>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <CallTarget Condition="$(MyBeforeCompileTimestamp) !=   
          %(IntermediateAssembly.ModifiedTime)" Targets="MyTarget" /> 
  </Target>
```

Comment: Unfortunately IntermediateAssebmly.modifiedTime is empty so I don't think I can use it.

Comment: So that would mean it has not changed since the last build.

Comment: Take a look at Incremental bulinding as well.                        How to: Build Incrementally               http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171483.aspx